# Change DateTimeField FORMAT in Django version 3.2.2

Tags: django, datetime, format, python-datetime, django-3.2

I'm trying to change DateTime format for all date time objects in my project.
I want to format :

```
    21-06-2021 14:02:12
```

My settings

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Tunis'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False  
USE_TZ = True
```

Result:

```
%21-%06-%2021 %14:%Jun:%st
```

Comment: `DATETIME_FORMAT` does not use Python's datetime module syntax, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) on what types of format strings are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`DATETIME_FORMAT`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#datetime-format) works with the formatting specifications like PHP does that.

So as format, you should use:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y H:i:s'
```

Note that the [formatting is slightly different [PHP datetime specs]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). PHP uses `i` for the minutes; and a *lowercase* `s` for the seconds:

| format character | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| … | … | … |
| i | Minutes with leading zeros | `00` to `59` |
| s | Seconds with leading zeros | `00` through `59` |
| … | … | … |

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) also has the format characters listed as [@AbdulAzizBarkat says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068581/change-datetimefield-format-in-django-version-3-2-2/68068637#comment120308252_68068637).

Comment: This link would be better for a comprehensive list than the PHP one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date :) Since the documentation states: "Uses a similar format to PHP’s `date()` function with some differences"

Comment: Thank you both  for your help. I checked the django documentation and the available format strings.
the new format is : DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'. it works. But i don't know why in my templates result be like :  %21-%06-%2021 %14:%28:%18 with % .

Comment: @JiheneBengamra: because it does not parses the `%` as a prefix for a variable but just a character to yield. It thus will generate a string with `%`, the day of the month (`d`), so `21`, etc. However Django, the `DateTimeFIeld `input_formats` use percentage formatting (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield), so it uses two datetime formats, hence the confusion.